# Get values and fields from BindingResult

Tags: java, spring

I have method which have BindingResult.

```
@PostMapping("/spare-create")
    public String saveSpare(@Valid Spares spares, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            attributes.addAttribute("orderNumberError", spares.getOrderNumber());
            attributes.addAttribute("orderMarkError", spares.getOrderMark());           
            List<ObjectError> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors();
            errors.forEach(element -> System.out.print(errors + ""));
            
            return "redirect:/ab2";
        } else {
            sparesServiceImpl.saveSpares(spares);
            return "redirect:/new-docs";
        }
    }
```

I tried to get all errors, but get output like

```
[Field error in object 'spares' on field 'orderNumber': rejected value [12345]; codes [Size.spares.orderNumber,Size.orderNumber,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spares.orderNumber,orderNumber]; arguments []; default message [orderNumber],2147483647,6]; default message [размер должен находиться в диапазоне от 6 до 2147483647]]
```

How can I get data in format like: "Field and value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're interested only in **field errors** you can call `getFieldErrors()` method on `BindingResult` instead of `getAllErrors()`, which will return collection of `FieldError`s instead of `ObjectError`s.

`FieldError` provides access to field name and rejected value, so you can achieve your goal like that:

```java
bindingResult.getFieldErrors()
                .forEach(e -> System.out.println(
                        "field: " + e.getField() + ", rejected value: " + e.getRejectedValue()));
```